# BitmapFactory.getByteArray only works if the byte array come from storage

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to create a program that processes images directly from the Camera2 preview, and I keep running into a problem when it comes to actually processing the incoming images.

In my **OnImageAvailableListener.onImageAvailable()** callback, I'm getting an `ImageReader` object, from which I **acquireNextImage()** and pass that Image object into my helper function. From there, I convert it into a byte array, and attempt to do the processing. Instead, every time I get to the part where I convert it to `Bitmap`, the `BitmapFactory.getByteArray` returns null, even though the byte array is a properly-formatted JPEG.

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
        = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
        Image image = imageReader.acquireNextImage();
        ProcessBarcode(image);
        image.close();
    }
};

private void ProcessBarcode(Image image) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    int bufferSize = buffer.remaining();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
    buffer.get(bytes);

    FileOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
        output.write(bytes);
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Do something clever
    }

    // This call FAILS
    //Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, buffer.remaining(), o);

    // But this call WORKS?
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath());

    detector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(getActivity())
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.EAN_13 | Barcode.ISBN)
            .build();

    if (b != null) {
        Frame isbnFrame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(b).build();
        SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detector.detect(isbnFrame);

        if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
            Log.d("Barcode decoded: ",barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No barcode detected");
        }
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "No bitmap detected");
    }
}
```

The `ImageReader` is set up like:

```
mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG, 2);
mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);
```

Basically what I see is that if I use the byte array directly without first saving it to the internal memory, the camera preview is fast and snappy, although the `Bitmap` is always null so I'm not actually performing any processing. If I save the byte array to the memory, then I get maybe 2-3fps, but the processing works as I'm intending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the call to `buffer.get(bytes)`, `buffer.remaining()` will return 0, since you just read through the whole ByteBuffer. `remaining()` tells you how many bytes are left between your current position and the limit of the buffer, and calls to `get()` move the position forward by the number of bytes read.

Therefore, when you do `decodeByteArray(bytes,0, buffer.remaining(), 0)`, you don't actually decode any bytes.

If you try `decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, 0)`, does it work?

Comment: Thanks Eddy! Getting the `bytes.length` directly instead of `buffer.remaining()` solved the problem. I'm still having the horrific scan rate, but I think that's a matter of decoding the barcode, and not anything related to capturing the images.

Comment: If you want high frame rate, do not capture JPEGs - those generally are slow (1-3 fps generally, 10fps at best).  Use ImageFormat.YUV_420_888 instead, which at preview resolutions at least is guaranteed to operate at 30fps.  You should also probably avoid creating a new barcode scanner for each image; I'd assume you can reuse one multiple times.

Comment: I had found another thread that touched on this topic (though not my obvious mistake), and it suggested also the YUV_420_888 format, so I'll be switching to that shortly. I did fix my framerate in the preview mode by filtering out the frames that were captured when the camera hadn't yet acquired the AF and AE locks. So now I'm displaying all preview frames, but only doing the barcode scanning after I have a positive lock with the camera. It's back to near-realtime.